# SQL Exclude Records with multiple values based on values from a different column

Tags: sql

In SQL I have a list of ID's and their REC Number associated with it. My goal is to remove the row with the 0 RECNO but only if there is another row with a non 0 RECNO.

Before:

```
DLREC#  RECNO
3583   | 0
586    | 0
3589   | 0
3589   | 123456789
3609   | 0
3650   | 0
3650   | 451230149
```

After:

```
DLREC#  RECNO
3583   | 0
3586   | 0
3589   | 123456789
3609   | 0
3650   | 451230149
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach with the sample data would be `MAX`

```
select
   [DLREC#]
   ,max(RECNO)
from YourTable
group by [DLREC#]
```

**For SQL Server**

Another method would be a window functions, if you had more values for each `DLREC#`

```
with cte as(
select *
   ,RN = row_number() over (partition by [DLREC#] order by RECNO)
   ,CT = count(*) over (partition by [DLREC#]))

select
   [DLREC#]
   ,RECNO
from CTE 
where (RN != 1 and CT > 1) or (RN = 1 and CT = 1)
```

Comment: I made the max() function work the way I needed it to. I guess I didn't think that would work correct but it did. Thanks!

Comment: No sweat! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` with `delete`:

```
delete t from t
    where recno = 0 and
          exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.dlrec = t.dlrec and t2.recno <> 0);
```